# How to skip =<2 blank row using Datatable C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Allow users to leave completely empty one or two empty rows. If any of the cells in rows have been filled out, then call out for the users to fill out the rest of the cells and tell them which row/line that cell lives in to fill.

Ideal logic to implement is: If empty row is found, skip it and go the the next row and find if any cell is left to fill,if found empty, skip go the next one.

I have two classes. The class below makes sure if the row is completely empty.

```
 public bool isRowEmpty(DataTable dt, int index)
    {
        // check if index exists, if not returns false
        // it will means that the row is "not empty"
        if (index >= dt.Rows.Count || index < 0)
            return false;

        // Get row
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[index];

        // Amount of empty columns
        int emptyQt = 0;
        // Run thourgh columns to check if any of them are empty
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // If empty, add +1 to the amount of empty columns
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr.ItemArray[i].ToString()))
            emptyQt++;

        }
        // if the amount of empty columns is equals to the amount of 
        //columns, it means that the whole row is empty
        return emptyQt == dr.Table.Columns.Count;
    }
```

Using the class above, I determine which row is empty within the next class, if found empty I will skip and go the next row, if found not empty find any cells that are not filled.

But the code below is not skipping the complete blank rows. Any insights?

```
 public DataValidationModel Validate(DataTable data, IList<FieldModel> fields)
        {
            var fieldsSorted = fields.Where(f => f.IsInTaxonomy == true).OrderBy(f => f.TaxonomyPosition).ToList();

            var model = new DataValidationModel()
            {
                Errors = new List<RowErrorModel>()
            };

            int rowCounter = 7;

            for (int i =0; i < data.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //Rows.Count - 1, 
            {
                if (!isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter-1) && isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter) && !isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter + 1))
                    i+=1;


                if (data.Rows[rowCounter][0] == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Rows[i][0].ToString()))
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "The name cannot be blank."
                    });

                }
                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["Site"] == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Rows[i]["Site"].ToString()))
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "Site is required."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["start date"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "start date is required."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["end date"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "end date is required."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["Placement Type"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "Placement Type is required."
                    });

                }
                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["Channel"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "Channel is required."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["Environment"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "Environment is required."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["rate type"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "rate is required when a rate type is not blank."
                    });

                }

                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["units"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "units is required when a rate type is not blank."
                    });

                }
                if (data.Rows[rowCounter]["cost"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    model.Errors.Add(new RowErrorModel()
                    {
                        Row = rowCounter,
                        Error = "cost is required when a rate type is not blank."
                    });

                }


      model.Errors = model.Errors.OrderBy(f => f.Row).ToList();

            return model;
        }
```

Comment: Check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead

Comment: I dont understand why you dont use `continue` when you have found out that the row is empty. Why the "magic" `i+=1` and then continue with your logic. And what is this `rowCounter = 7` logic?

Comment: @Rahul  isRowEmpty already helps me to find a complete empty rows, my question is if found complete empty, how to skip that row and go the next row

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show you an example which is not related to your additional logic.

```
public bool isRowEmpty(DataTable dt, int index)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[index];
    return dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .All(c => row.IsNull(c) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[c].ToString()));
}
```

In the `foreach` or `for`-loop you just need to use `continue`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (isRowEmpty(data, i))
        continue;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `continue` once you found that the row is empty per your comment like

```
        for (int i =0; i < data.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //Rows.Count - 1, 
        {
            if (!isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter-1) && isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter) && !isRowEmpty(data, rowCounter + 1))
                continue; // this one here, which will jump to next iteration
```